# Difference between using and not using Model Classes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know the pros and cons of the following scenarios:

1. Using a Model Class?
2. Decoding the API data using `json.decode()` and using a copy of that data instead of using a model class?

Currently, I am a lot into using the second scenario and I wonder what could that result into going forward?

Comment: I've found model classes to be helpful to transform data from external sources to a form that makes more sense for use within the application. For example, fields that your app calculates, or combing data from multiple sources or API calls into one model class, omitting data that you don't care about, etc. They also can help protect against errors you might encounter when the shape of data from sources out of your control changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the developer's preference whether you use model class or not but there are definitely pros of using model class over refraining to use it.

As Dart is a statically typed language it is best practice to benefit from its typed nature. It's what model classes do, it gives you power of typed nature. It becomes less error-prone. It also provides features like `Intellisense`, for example code completion.